# How to get Cookies from third-part request

Tags: angular

My angular application will get called from third party application.

The third-party application will set some cookies before calling my application.

I want to retrieve those cookies before processing them further.

I have implemented RouteGuardService which get gets called when the third-party request landed my application.

I can see the cookie set by the third-party application in the cookies tab.

I am using ngx-cookie-service to read the cookies in the browser.

But I am unable to retrieve those values.

Can you please tell me how to get COOKIES set by a third-party application?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brandon mentioned, cookies are set as Http Only.

Thanks